# How to check if values in one column match a specific amount of values in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the Doctors that possess only three fruit that is common to all the doctors - Apple, Kiwi, and Orange. Here is the code for me to pull the data:

```
SELECT Doctor AS [Dr Name], Fruit_Staff_Map.ID AS [Physician ID], fruit.Name

FROM Staff

INNER JOIN Fruit_Staff_Map ON Staff.staffKey=Fruit.staffKey
INNER JOIN Fruit ON Fruit_Staff_Map.fruitKey=Fruit.fruitKey

WHERE
Staff.isActive = 'true'
```

Which gives the result of

```
Dr Name    Physician ID Fruit
Dr Helga    94233       apple
Dr Helga    94233       orange
Dr Helga    94233       strawberry
Dr Helga    94233       blueberry
Dr Helga    94233       kiwi
Dr Robert   95555       orange
Dr Robert   95555       apple
Dr Robert   95555       kiwi
Dr James    94074       apple
Dr James    94074       kiwi
Dr James    94074       orange
Dr James    94074       strawberry
Dr James    94074       blueberry
Dr James    94074       apple
Dr James    94074       banana
Dr Helga    96552       kiwi
Dr Helga    96552       orange
Dr Helga    96552       apple
Dr Tania    93688       kiwi
Dr Tania    93688       apple
Dr Tania    93688       banana
Dr Tania    93688       orange
```

As you see, every single doctor has a kiwi, orange, and an apple. I want the Doctors that ONLY have a kiwi, orange and apple. Thus, my result should look like:

```
Dr Robert   95555       orange
Dr Robert   95555       apple
Dr Robert   95555       kiwi
Dr Helga    96552       kiwi
Dr Helga    96552       orange
Dr Helga    96552       apple
```

I'm having multiple problems trying to work this one out. The big barrier for me is how to exclude those doctors that own more than those three fruits.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add an IN condition for filtering the 3 fruits and Partitioned Row_Number() for identifying  doctors that own more than those three fruits.

```
     SELECT [Dr Name] ,
            [Physician ID] ,
            fruitName
     FROM   ( SELECT    Doctor AS [Dr Name] ,
                        Fruit_Staff_Map.ID AS [Physician ID] ,
                        fruit.NAME fruitName ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Doctor, fruit.NAME ORDER BY Doctor ) ctr
              FROM      Staff
                        INNER JOIN Fruit_Staff_Map ON Staff.staffKey = Fruit.staffKey
                        INNER JOIN Fruit ON Fruit_Staff_Map.fruitKey = Fruit.fruitKey
              WHERE     Staff.isActive = 'true'
                        AND fruit.NAME IN ( 'kiwi', 'orange', 'apple' )
            ) T
     WHERE  ctr = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm.  You can get the fruits common to all doctors by doing:

```
select fs.fruitKey
from fruit_staff fs
group by fs.fruitKey
having count(*) = (select count(*) from staff where isActive = 'true')
```

Then, you can incorporate this into a query using `group_concat()` to compare the lists:

```
select s.doctor
from staff s join
     fruit_staff fs
     on s.staffkey = fs.staffkey
group by s.doctor
having group_concat(fs.fruitKey order by fs.fruitkey) = 
        (select group_concat(fruitkey order by fruitkey)
         from (select fs.fruitKey
               from fruit_staff fs
               group by fs.fruitKey
               having count(*) = (select count(*) from staff where isActive = 'true')
              ) fs
        );
```